# How to pass in any object for custom hook react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to pass in any object for typescript in react custom hooks so it could work with any form. I have placed `initObj` temporarily but not sure what to do

```
interface initObj {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const useForm = (initialState: initObj) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState<initObj>(initialState);

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.persist();
    setForm((f) => ({ ...f, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  };
  const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return { form, handleChange, onSubmit } as const;
};
```

Comment: Off topic: no need to persist that event. `const { name, value } = e.target; setForm(f => ({ ...f, [name]: value }));`

Comment: Any  reason why? I was watching a tutorial and they added it

Comment: Event objects in React are pooled and reused to avoid the overhead of creating them and GC; and for most use cases that works just fine. When you persist them they are taken out of this pool, because React doesn't know whether/when it will be able to reuse them. The code above, I don't even want to call it an optimization, you won't notice any difference. It comes more from a thought of: I can do this without interfering with React, and it doesn't cost me anything. So, don't go out of your way to avoid `event.persist()`, it's not worth it, but if you can avoid it for free, why not?

Comment: I see thanks for your explanation. will update it

Answer (score 1):

Use a generic:

```js
const useForm = <T extends Record<string, any>>(initialState: T) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialState);

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.persist();
    setForm((f) => ({ ...f, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  };
  const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return { form, handleChange, onSubmit } as const;
};
```